# Finding a basis and dimension for the subspace...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | x+y+z = 0\}$ be a subspace of vector space. Find a basis and dimension for the subspace.

I'm not sure if I am approaching this correctly.

I started off by rewriting the plane as:

$x = -y-z$

$y = -x-z$

$z = -x-y$

Which gives me the vector $(-y-z, -x-z, -x-y)$ which can be broken down into $x(0,-1,-1) + y(-1,0,-1) + z(-1,-1,0)$.

This means that $S = sp\{(0,-1,-1), (-1,0,-1), (-1,-1,0)\}$

You can express this as a matrix and row reduce to see that you get a rank of 3. What can I conclude from this? I get pivots along the diagonal, and it is a 3x3 matrix, so it is safe to say thsoe vectors are linearly independent, and so they do form a basis. Furthermore, since we have three basis vectors, then the dimension of the subspace is 3.

But I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x+y+z=0$$

Let $y=s$, let $z=t$, then $x = -s-t$

Hence we can write $\begin{bmatrix}  x\\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix}  -1\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}  -1\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Try to see if you can read off the basis from here.

Remark about your approach: It doesn't seems that $(0,-1,-1)$ is a solution to your equation.

Comment: As you were typing that I just realized it isn't valid. As you did, I fixed x in terms of the other variables and I got the same equation as you did, so S = span{(-1, 1,0) , (-1, 0, 1)}. But I am not sure how to show that these two vectors are linearly independent as there isn't much to row reduce?

Comment: For only two vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$, if they are non-zero and they are not multiple of each other, then they are linearly independent. Try to  check from definition,  $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = 0$, try to prove that $c_1=c_2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these vector aren't linearly independent.
An element of $S$ can be written as
$$(-y-z,y,z) = y(-1,1,0) + z(-1,0,1),$$
for some $y,z\in\mathbb R$.
Then $S={\rm span}\{(-1,1,0), (-1,0,1)\}$.

Now, it is just verify that these vectors are indeed linearly independent.

Therefore, $\dim S = 2$ and $\{(-1,1,0), (-1,0,1)\}$ is a basis for $S$.